# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет!

создал проект rails+webpacker+vue, но почему-то при попытке создать первый объект в проекте выдаёт ошибку в консоли chrome:

> ```
> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1291 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
> at normalizeProps (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1291)
> at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1363)
> at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1372)
> at Vue$3.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:4268)
> at new Vue$3 (vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:4384)
> at HTMLDocument.eval (hello_vue.js?94ab:29)
> at Object.t.dispatch (turbolinks.self-...)
> ....
> ```

файл hello_vue.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import TurbolinksAdapter from "vue-turbolinks"
import VueResource from "vue-resource"

Vue.use(VueResource);

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

Vue.http.headers.common["X-CSRF-Token"] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content");

var element = document.getElementById("team-form")

if(element != null){

    var team = JSON.parse(element.dataset.team);
    var players_attributes = JSON.parse(element.dataset.playersAttributes);
    players_attributes.forEach(function(player){
        player._destroy = null  
    })
    team.players_attributes = players_attributes;

    var app = new Vue({
        el: element,
        mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter],
        data: function(){
            return{ team: team }
        },
        methods: {
            addPlayer: function(){
                team.players_attributes.push({
                id: null,
                name: "",
                _destroy: null
                })
            }
        }
    });
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил строку mixins: [TurbolinksAdapter]
и добавил Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter) после Vue.use(VueResource)и всё заработало